# Access file directory path with Streamreader in local computer

Tags: c#, get, streamreader, webapi

I should save file by request get 
The request  contain file name and URL to file for content,
I have WebApi that run in server,
I want to set taht URL of file be from local computer and not from server,
But the WebApi run in server so if I set to take directory path it take path of server,
How can I set that take directory path from local computer where I run the URL?

My Code:

```
     [HttpGet("SetConfiguration")]
     public IActionResult SetConfiguration(string fileName, string url)
     {

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(@"D:/" + fileName + @".json"))
         {
             Logger._logger.Debug("File " + fileName + " already exists");
             return BadRequest("File " + fileName + " already exists");
         }
         else
         {
             string content = "";
             using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(url))
             {
                 try
                 {
                     content = sr.ReadToEnd();
                 }
                 catch
                 {
                     Logger._logger.Debug("File is not a valid json ");
                     return BadRequest("File is not a valid json ");
                 }
             }
             using (StreamWriter fileStream = new StreamWriter(@"D:/" + fileName + @".json", false))
             {
                 try
                 {
                     fileStream.WriteLine(content);

                 }
                 catch
                 {
                     Logger._logger.Debug("content is not a valid json ");
                     return BadRequest("content is not a valid json ");
                 }
             }
             return Ok("file " + fileName + " saved");
         }
     }
```

Comment: It is not good to save smth on the server on GET request. There are special POST and PUT requests for it

Comment: Why do you create `StreamReader` from `url` ?

Comment: I created StreamReader becouse I want to read the content from file, Which sent in url

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to save the file on the server from the client?

What you need to do is send the file from the client to the server (for example, if it's an image you can send it in base64 in POST) or use/create an uploader component to upload the file to your server (for example - by chunk of data).

If your client is written in javascript, [Here](https://slashuploader.com/)'s a nice plugin for uploading files.

Comment: I didn't download it, But don't have client I use in service that run in server ant I turn to his by url with IP of server.

Comment: If you just enter the url to the API in the browser without using a client software, then there's no way you can upload a file to the server..